# How to fix 'member modifier 'protected' must precede the member type and name when scripting DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new to Unity. Trying to to fix an earlier problem (my video not playing on top of my image target after I built for Android) by adding some instructions on the DefaultTrackableEventHandler to help play the vid.

I seem to keep getting stuck at the same point when it says

> 'Member modifier 'protected' must precede the member type and number

I am not sure what this exactly means and how I can fix it.

I would be entirely grateful if someone knows and can help. Thank you!

When it says:

- `trackingfound();` I have added `VideoPlayer.play();`
- `trackinglost();` I have added `VideoPlayer.stop();`

Here is my code

```c#
/*==============================================================================
 *    Copyright (c) 2017 PTC Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *    Copyright (c) 2010-2014 Qualcomm Connected Experiences, Inc.
 *    All Rights Reserved.
 *    Confidential and Proprietary - Protected under copyright and other laws.          
 *=============================================================================*/

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using Vuforia;

/// <summary>
/// A custom handler that implements the ITrackableEventHandler interface.
///
/// Changes made to this file could be overwritten when upgrading the Vuforia version.
/// When implementing custom event handler behavior, consider inheriting from this class instead.
/// </summary>
public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{
    public UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer

    #region PROTECTED_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    protected TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
    protected TrackableBehaviour.Status m_PreviousStatus;
    protected TrackableBehaviour.Status m_NewStatus;

    #endregion // PROTECTED_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    #region UNITY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
            mTrackableBehaviour.UnregisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }

    #endregion // UNITY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    #region PUBLIC_METHODS

    /// <summary>
    ///     Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
    ///     tracking state changes.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        m_PreviousStatus = previousStatus;
        m_NewStatus = newStatus;

        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED 
            || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED 
            || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
            OnTrackingFound();
            VideoPlayer.play(); 
        }
        else if (previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED 
                 && newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NO_POSE)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
            OnTrackingLost();
            VideoPlayer.stop(); 
        }
        else
        {
            // For combo of previousStatus=UNKNOWN + newStatus=UNKNOWN|NOT_FOUND
            // Vuforia is starting, but tracking has not been lost or found yet
            // Call OnTrackingLost() to hide the augmentations
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
    }

    #endregion // PUBLIC_METHODS

    #region PROTECTED_METHODS

    protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Enable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable canvas':
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = true;
    }

    protected virtual void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Disable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable canvas':
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = false;
    }

    #endregion // PROTECTED_METHODS
}
```

Comment: At first sight, you missed a semi-colon after declaring de `VideoPlayer` variable.

Comment: haha oh yes!! didn't notice that! thanks

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

With your current code structure, I noticed that you have missed the variable name and you are trying to call play method through VideoPlayer class. Did some modifications.

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using Vuforia;

public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{
    public UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer _videoPlayer;
    #region PROTECTED_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    protected TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
    protected TrackableBehaviour.Status m_PreviousStatus;
    protected TrackableBehaviour.Status m_NewStatus;

    #endregion // PROTECTED_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    #region UNITY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
            mTrackableBehaviour.UnregisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }

    #endregion // UNITY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    #region PUBLIC_METHODS

    /// <summary>
    ///     Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
    ///     tracking state changes.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
        TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        m_PreviousStatus = previousStatus;
        m_NewStatus = newStatus;

        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
            OnTrackingFound();
            _videoPlayer.Play();
        }
        else if (previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED &&
                 newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NO_POSE)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
            OnTrackingLost();
            _videoPlayer.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            // For combo of previousStatus=UNKNOWN + newStatus=UNKNOWN|NOT_FOUND
            // Vuforia is starting, but tracking has not been lost or found yet
            // Call OnTrackingLost() to hide the augmentations
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
    }

    #endregion // PUBLIC_METHODS

    #region PROTECTED_METHODS

    protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Enable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable canvas':
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = true;
    }


    protected virtual void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Disable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable canvas':
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = false;
    }

    #endregion // PROTECTED_METHODS
}
```

---

You should stop the video on `OnTrackingLost`. One thing, `Videoplayer` doesn't use normal `DefaultTrackableEventHandler`. There is an assetstore package named as Vuforia core samples. It contains a separate videoplayerEventhandler that pauses/resume a video when the marker is lost.

I made a project a few months ago. You can download it and use it :). It plays several videos that come from the metadata from cloud reco.

Link: https://github.com/MuhammadFarhanAqeel/AR-videoplayer-with-vuforia-cloud-reco

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi Muhammad! Thanks for your response. I have had a look at your project but I  am still stuck at the same part. Would you mind breaking it down for me as I am new and very confused haha. can't seem to find Vuforia core samples. Thank you!!!

Comment: Found some variable issues in your script. edited my answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your help!! I really appreciate it. Although now a new error has come up  : The type or namespace name 'DefaultTrackableEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (VuforiaEditorScripts)

Comment: my mistake, i changed the name of script. Edited the answer.

Comment: Kindly mark this as answer if it helped and solved the issue so that other people can see.